# set DropDownListFor with value ng-model instead SelectedIndex

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-views

I have DropDownListFor in MVC view, with this line:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserOffice, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", data_ng_model = "OfficeID", data_ng_options = "I.Id as I.Name  for I in OfficeList", @id = "UserOffice" })
```

I need to store in "m.UserOffice" the "data_ng_model" value instead Selected index.

how can I do it ?

Comment: `m` is the model coming from the controller.  What are you wanting to do with this value after you have set it?

Comment: i need to store the ng-model value inside. for example: if SelectedIndex is "2", i want to store in m.UserOffice the value "213".

Comment: can someone give a hint maybe ?

Comment: Where do you want to store it?  You should be posting the chosen value back to your controller for processing.

Comment: also, if there is an option , how can i send the ng-model value to the controller ?
this is the html post:
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddUser", "AdminUsers"))

Comment: You'd probably have to send that value over javascript